# Design an UI similar to GO SMS Pro

Tags: android, sms, android-listview

HI i'm designing a SMS app which requires to display the conversation as in the threaded sms.i just want a layout where my text are left aligned and the other on the right with a specified shape which is set as the background (just like in callout in MS-Word)

just like the following image http://www.google.co.in/imgres?q=go+sms+pro&um=1&hl=en&biw=1366&bih=677&tbm=isch&tbnid=Q9R7aXMMKBliqM:&imgrefurl=http://resdownload.com/mobile/2458-go-sms-pro-3-63-android.html&docid=Rt1nxkZhIeNHmM&w=300&h=499&ei=LTFfTtTVIoy3rAf_88mgDw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=346&vpy=275&dur=1665&hovh=290&hovw=174&tx=87&ty=207&page=1&tbnh=123&tbnw=74&start=0&ndsp=39&ved=1t:429,r:21,s:0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

create a listview and in getView method from adapter, show background depending on message (if it's received or sent) and in list item from xml arrange item on left or right side, depending on prefferences